# Inserting data with MYSQL but nothing happens

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm trying to insert data from my app to the MYSQL database. Im using `HttpURLConnection` to open a connection and writing it with a `BufferedWriter`. Everything works (nothing catches any exception) but somehow no data is being inserted into the table. (Im following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOsZHuu8Qog) tutorial).

I'm using the `AsyncTask` to do the networking in the background. As shown below I've created a new class who's extending from `AsyncTask`.

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
```

This is the doInBackground method.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
{
    String registerUrl = "http://localhost/APPoint/register.php";
    String method = strings[0];
    if (method.equals("register"))
    {
        try
        {
            String gebruikersnaam = strings[1];
            String wachtwoord = strings[2];
            String voornaam = strings[3];
            String tussenvoegsel = strings[4];
            String achternaam = strings[5];
            String bedrijfsnaam = strings[6];
            String email = strings[7];
            String telefoonnummer = strings[8];
            URL url = new URL(registerUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("Gebruikersnaam", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(gebruikersnaam, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("wachtwoord", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(wachtwoord, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("voornaam", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(voornaam, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("tussenvoegsel", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(tussenvoegsel, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("achternaam", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(achternaam, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("bedrijfsnaam", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(bedrijfsnaam, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("telefoonnummer", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(telefoonnummer, "UTF-8");
            try {
                bw.write(data);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bw.flush();
            InputStream inputS = conn.getInputStream();
            inputS.close();
            bw.close();
            OS.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Registreren voltooid";
    }
    return null;
}
```

My php DB connection initializer.

```
<?php

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', '');
define('DB', 'appoint');

$conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . DB . ';host=' . HOST, USER, PASS);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

My register.php file

```
<?php
$username = filter_var(trim($_POST['gebruikersnaam']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$password = filter_var(trim($_POST['wachtwoord']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$voornaam = filter_var(trim($_POST['voornaam']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$tussenvoegsel = filter_var(trim($_POST['tussenvoegsel']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$achternaam = filter_var(trim($_POST['achternaam']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$bedrijfsnaam = filter_var(trim($_POST['bedrijfsnaam']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$telefoonnummer = filter_var(trim($_POST['telefoonnummer']), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

if ($username == '' || $password == '' || $voornaam == '' || $tussenvoegsel == '' || $achternaam == '' || $bedrijfsnaam == '' || $email == '' || $telefoonnummer == '') {
    //echo 'Verplichte velden zijn niet ingevoerd!';
} else {
    require_once('DBConnect.php');

    $stmnt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO gebruikers (`gebruikersnaam`, `wachtwoord`, `voornaam`, `tussenvoegsel`, `achternaam`, `bedrijfsnaam`, `email`, `telefoonnummer`) "
            . "VALUES (?, ? , ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    try {
        $stmnt->execute(array($username, $password, $voornaam, $tussenvoegsel, $achternaam, $bedrijfsnaam, $email, $telefoonnummer));
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        if ($ex->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
            echo 'duplicate entry';
        } else {
            var_dump($ex);
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought my URL was wrong. I've tried using:

```
"http://127.0.0.1/APPoint/register.php"
"http://localhost/APPoint/register.php"
"http://10.0.2.2/APPoint/register.php"
"http://192.168.0.1/APPoint/register.php"
```

Nothing seems to do the job. If anyone could have some input would be appreciated.

**Edit** I should've mentioned that i'm not using an AVD to test the code. Im using my own samsung device for this.

**Edit** adding the execute for backgroundtask

```
if(!errors)
        {
            String method = "register";
            BackgroundTask bgTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
            bgTask.execute(method, gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord, voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, bedrijfsnaam, email, telefoonnummer);
            finish();
        }
```

**Edit** On logcat this error shows up while running with AVD (probably the android bug): 
getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer 0xb4095170 
After a google search it looks like an some android error regarding the permissions. But i already have a internet permission in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: In `$_POST['gebruikersnaam']` variable is lowercase but in `URLEncoder.encode("Gebruikersnaam", "UTF-8")` starts with uppercase

Comment: @MarkoMets Thanks for pointing that out, unfortunally no successful result.

Comment: Is your registerUrl correct?

Comment: @MarkoMets the php files are in C:\wamp64\www\APPoint (using wamp) so it should be good yes.

Comment: Well if you use your own device then localhost will point to your device. Your server is on your PC, so instead of localhost use your PC ip. And check that port is correct.

Comment: I've tried `String registerUrl = "http://192.168.2.5APPoint/register.php";`. Didn't seem to work on my device. I started up the AVD I had set up from before and used the URL's listed in the original post. They didnt seem to work.

Comment: Can you access your server from browser? And that URL should be http://192.168.2.5/APPoint/register.php

Comment: Yes. only it gives me a bunch of undefined index error because the POST is empty (unrelated I guess).

Comment: Is the php script executed when called from app? Create some log file in php and log the variables.

Comment: How can I catch any logs with php?

Comment: Just write to file.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that. I might have found my problem. It didnt even get to the php script. After looking some more into the IP I found out that 192.168.2.5 as registerIP works on an AVD. Any suggestions how I could get it to work on my samsung device ? I'm getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.2.5/APPoint/register.php` on my device

Comment: Well are you on the same subnet?

Comment: Same subnet, Trying to access the C:/wamp/www/APPoint/register.php I get a connection refused error all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Request is sent to server when you call conn.getInputStream() or conn.getResponseCode(). If you don't do that nothing happens. Please add one of these methods to your doInBackground().

Comment: Edited, but still nothing. see original post.

Comment: @Necati Probably you should put getInputStream() before closing streams. Actually you just need to debug. Is http request actually sent? Is http request actually received by you php script? And so on.

Comment: Changed the position of inputstream. put it after the bw.flush(), check post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call the execute() method for the AsyncTask?

How do you host your server to the app? You cannot access the localhost using your phone.

There is a smart tool called ngrok to open your localhost to the internet. It is much easy in android development to use your localhost as a server for the android app.
Visit https://ngrok.com

Comment: Added the executing part of backgroundTask part of the code. check post please.